# Closed form for $n$-th derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$ for general $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let's assume we have an inifinitely differentiable real valued function $f(x)$, and we have a closed form expression for all its derivatives. Is it then possible to find a closed form for the $n$-th derivative of $\sqrt{f(x)}$?

Comment: Why do you need a closed form?

Comment: I'm interested in finding the taylor expansion of a function that has messy derivatives, but the square of this function has easy derivatives.

Comment: In this case, you may want to try implicit differentiation of $g^2=f$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't be pretty, but you can use [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):
$$
{d^n \over dx^n} g(f(x))
=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,m_2!\,\cdots\,m_n!}
g^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(f(x))
\prod_{j=1}^n\left(\frac{f^{(j)}(x)}{j!}\right)^{m_j}
$$
where the sum is over all $(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_n)$ such that
$$
1\cdot m_1+2\cdot m_2+3\cdot m_3+\cdots+n\cdot m_n=n
$$
with $g(x)=\sqrt{x}$, whose $n$-th derivatives are easy to compute for all $n$.

Comment: That escalated quickly! Interesting formula.